# I am trying to add Google Analytics tracking to my public Github Page, but I am worried about privacy

Tags: github, google-analytics, adsense

I have a domain from GoDaddy that I changed the DNS settings for and redirected to a public Github Page of mine. I just signed up for Google Analytics tracking, but it's telling me to put the Global Site Tag tracking code in the HTML head of my page. I am curious if this tracking code is supposed to remain private, and if so, how am I supposed to track my Github Page unless I upgrade to a Pro page and make my repository private? I had the same concern regarding adding Google Adsense to my page. I appreciate any help anyone can provide! :D

Comment: If it's supposed to be in the HTML for your page, they couldn't possibly want it to be private, since the HTML for your page isn't private.

Answer (score 1):

### Analytics code is not private

*If you code looks like this:*

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Then you are probably worry about **UA-XXXXX-Y**, **but this is very public information.** You can just include it into your page.

#### Alternative approach

In case you need to hide it, then you have to send your statistical data to some proxy server that will enhance your hit with your "secret Property ID".